# How do I use build_full_result() in Boto3

Tags: python-3.x, boto3

I was Googling around to understand how boto3 paginator works, and found a solution that potentially doesn't require writing any logic with `NextToken` and While loops.

Still, I'm not quite sure what I'm getting when I'm using this:

```py
client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='eu-west-1')
results = (
   client.get_paginator('describe_instances')
   .paginate()
   .build_full_result()
)

print(results)
```

I got a huge JSON output and I'm not sure whether I got what I wanted, which is basically the output of all of my EC2 instances.

I'm also not sure how to loop over it, I keep getting `TypeError: string indices must be integers` which didn't happen before when I used something like:

```py
for instance in response_iterator:
    instance = instance['Reservations'][0]
    instance_id = instance['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']
    print(instance_id)
```

I would love to understand how to use the `build_full_result()` method.

I saw a [post](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/3001) that says that it's not documented yet, pretty recent to now (as of writing this post).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting find.. this isn't mentioned anywhere in the [latest version of boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html), however it does appear to properly return all available results.

Below is an example from Lambda that shows how to perform a simple loop through the response.. you can update the last two lines to handle the [response syntax from EC2 describe instances](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances).

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('lambda')

results = (
   client.get_paginator('list_functions')
   .paginate()
   .build_full_result()
)

for result in results['Functions']:
    print(result['FunctionName'])
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the correct response syntax, I'm getting the full results now. I am also able to filter by adding the `Filters=[{'Name': 'tag:Key', 'Values': ['valueq]}` inside the `paginate()` function.